# How can I find the amount of decimal places of a number from a list of numbers in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

A text file has the following numbers:
1,2,3.02, 3.234,2.52

How can I find the amount of sig figs after the decimal point from that text file in python3 and up?

Comment: At what point are you stuck in trying out this yourself?

Comment: If your string numbers you can split them: '3.02'.split('.') Which returns a list. The second element of that list the the part after the decimal point. Use len() on that and you have your answer

Comment: I tried using a for loop with an if statement to find the amount of sig figs after the decimal point but I'm not sure what I need to put for my if statement to detect the sig figs after the decimal point. That's where I'm stuck at

Comment: please show what you tried by adding it to the question

Comment: @Slashx43, your problem is like in two parts you should break it down better. First part is reading the file. Second part is determining the number of sig(nificant) figures. Break it up that way and you will be able to solve it easily.

Comment: @unlockme I will give that a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the input file is something like below.

*input.txt*

```
1,2,3.02,3.234,2.52
```

So you can use this snippet to count significant figures.

```py
res = []
with open('input.txt') as file:
    number_list = file.readline().strip().split(',')
    for num in number_list:
        sig_fig = 0
        if '.' in number:
            sig_fig = len(number.split('.')[-1])
        res.append(sig_fig)
print(res)
```

Also there's another implementation by using `map`.

```py
def get_sig_fig(num):
    return len(num.split('.')[-1]) if '.' in num else 0

with open('input.txt') as file:
    number_list = file.readline().strip().split(',')
    res = list(map(get_sig_fig, number_list))
    print(res)
```

Comment: That works great! But what I need it to read it off a list like the one I had where it is separated by commas ?

Comment: @Slashx43 Based on this point, I updated my answer. Let's check it!

Comment: @mzrm it does read the amount of decimals in the line. It reads the total amount of decimals from all the numbers on the list. I need it to read each number and if it has a decimal point it needs to output how many decimal places that number has. Does that require to modify the whole code?

Comment: @Slashx43 what is the desired output for the sample input in your question?

Comment: the desired output would be according to our list of numbers "Decimal places of each number: 0, 0, 2, 3, 2" @mrzrm

Comment: @Slashx43 I upgraded my answer.